# How to access Display and speaker in C programming?

Tags: c, driver, hardware

I only know C programming.
Using C programming, I want to build my own library (to control my Display and Speakers) that's specifically useful for my projects.

I don't want any readymade libraries with different features, I just want **direct control** to **every pixel** of a computer (atleast my computer's display, I will think about cross platform later) and **every vibration** of my speaker(s).

How can I get this?

---

**First Edit:**
After getting some informations in the comment-section/answers, I came to an **understanding** that in modern computers, direct access is not possible as every aspect regarding Display and speaker is controlled by the OS, and I can only request the OS to display a graphics in it's **Window**  or play a sound by pre-encoding my sound in one of the supported audio formats (correct me if I'm wrong).

Now, let's change the scenario. I have my Display (with its driver hardware), my speaker (with its driver hardware), and a Micro-controller.

Now, by coding my own OS and booting it in my microcontroller, can I get **direct control** to **every pixel** of a computer and **every vibration** of my speaker(s).

Comment: What platform are you using? The solution would be different for every OS

Comment: in brevi, in modern OS - you cannot get direct control over hardware, you need to go through OS's drivers layer (HAL)

Comment: I have windows 11 and Ubuntu 20.04, I just prefer this accessibilty to be more straight forward (no trouble of 'layers'), it must be more direct. So, It doesn't matter which OS (among Windows 11 or Ubuntu 20.04), I just want this accessibility to be more direct.

Comment: Short answer, you can't: since 32 bits era, OS are designed to forbid that from user space. DOS days are over: I used to do that 30 years ago, now you must deal with at least a low-level interface like GDI or Direct2D on Windows. You can still expose a "raw" framebuffer to your application, but not like you wanted it. It's exactly the same for audio, mass storage, COM ports, etc.

Comment: @Everyone I have added new question by editing my question, please answer if possible. (I don't know whether everyone would be notified about my editing, so added this comment).

Comment: if you write your own OS - yes, you will have access to all hardware, just need to find (usually condifential) information about low level interfaces of your video/sound card

Comment: Asking how to get direct display access on your Windows computer, and on a microcontroller, are completely different questions and should be asked separately in separate questions. Also you will need to know which microcontroller and display you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. You have to get the OS to do it for you - in fact, that's the entire point of an OS. And that means either making system calls directly from assembly code (hard on Linux; practically impossible on Windows because they are undocumented) or using a library to tell the OS to do things.

You are probably interested in using a library that's as close to the OS as possible - "batteries not included" - so in Linux that would be something like ALSA (sound) and XCB (graphics) rather than something like Qt.

You can minimize your library usage - for example, if you make an array of pixels, and you only tell the OS "please create a window" and "please draw these pixels in my window" and "please play this sound data".

Of course it is also possible to tell it to make your program fullscreen so that the user can't see anything else. This is usually done by making a window and then making the window fullscreen. Linux does actually have ways to get more direct screen control - accessing the screen as a "framebuffer device" - but if you use this, you can't run any other graphics programs at the same time (not even the desktop). And you are still asking the operating system to put pixels on the screen - not talking to the hardware.

If you want to write a program that doesn't run with an OS, that's a completely different question (and still difficult).

Comment: Can I still have full access to the Display and speaker if the OS is built by me (booted in an Micro-controller, with sufficient RAM)? More detail in my edit of the question.

Comment: @ByteManager Yes. Then you should find information about your specific microcontroller. They usually have *extensive* "datasheets" containing all the information you could possibly need to know. Usually you read and write certain memory locations.

Comment: @ByteManager by the way, it **is** possible to write a program that runs on (for example) a laptop computer without an OS but it is fairly difficult, because laptop computers are designed in complex ways to run complex OSes. Most people would probably call that program "an OS"